# Add class on TD by click checkbox

Tags: jquery

actually i am trying to add class by click checkbox.. mean when i click checkbox that moment that TD only highlight .. say like add class. for better understanding manually i put class on last TD

http://jsfiddle.net/upXr8/2/  demo

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="common">
  <tr>
    <td>End Market IT KPI Dashboard</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>IT Services Report </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Incident &amp; Problem Ticket Details Report </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Change &amp; Request Ticket Details Report </td>
    <td class="highlight"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
$(".common").change(function() {
    $(this).closest('td').addClass("highlight", this.checked);
});
```

CSS

```
.highlight { background: red;}
td.highlight {background: red;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.on('click', 'input:checkbox')` instead :

```
// catch every click on a checkbox, localized into .common
$(".common").on('click', 'input:checkbox', function() {
    $(this).closest('td').toggleClass('highlight', this.checked);
});
// initialization
$('.common input:checkbox:checked').closest('td').addClass('highlight');
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/upXr8/10/)

Comment: any idea how can also to do when page loaded and all checked checked td also added class...

Answer (score 0):

use [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

```
$(this).closest('.td').toggleClass("highlight", this.checked);
```

---

Also the checkbox selector

```
$('.common input:checkbox').change(function () {
    $(this).closest('td').toggleClass("highlight", this.checked);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/A5YCT/)

Comment: thank you so much.. it work... but one thing it effect on 1st column checkbox 2nd column not effect.. any idea how ?

Answer (score 0):

Write:

```
$(".common input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(){
        $(this).closest('td').addClass("highlight");
});
$(".common input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {    
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $(this).closest('td').addClass("highlight");
    }
    else{
        $(this).closest('td').removeClass("highlight");
    }    
});
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/upXr8/9/)

Comment: any idea how can also to do when page loaded and all checked checked td also added class...thanks....